# What is Trace_MediaProvider.csv?

Tags: android

Trace_MediaProvider.csv was installed in Oppo Mobile Phone, I just wanted to understand what is the use of it. Can't find any answers in google. I Hope someone would help me here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is file and data sharing service used to share at any size and uses to transfer files much faster than http and ftp …….. you can download and read more on the following link:    https://fileninja.net/download/056rhJyfda/text_csv/trace_mediaprovider_csv.html

Comment: Does it mean that thing wasn't connected to others device or apps that are trying to spy or track my location? I'm confused, because it's keep coming back everytime I tried to delete it

Comment: because it is a network of almost every available networks in the internet and it is fast enough to travel any available short  route, and checkout the setting if it have one.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand